# Non-linear IV & DV time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, linear, stationarity, nonlinear-regression

I have temporal data that I try to analyze correctly. I have plotted my independent (let's call it x) and dependent variable (let's call it Y).
The pattern they show is pretty much the same.
Let's say from the period 1800 to 1950 it starts to decline, and then it flips in the opposite direction. My dependent variable does more or less the same thing actually.

Of course, I'd need to control for time, but what would the correct way to model this? An regression with a quatdratic term for time? And then within an ARIMA?

I know how to do this for a simple linear type of regression, just the quadratic/cubic part throws me off!

Thank you in advance

Comment: It sounds like your variables might be Cointegrated. If that is the case, you could use the Error Correction approach, like VECM. You might want to check for Cointegration.